# How to populate records to textbox & display part of that record in textbox using autocompleteextender.

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one textbox & `autocompletextender`. I have written method to populate `Records`(ID & name from particular table) to textbox. It works fine,but I want to know is it possible to populate records as combination of ID & name from particular table and after selecting that value, only ID should appear in textbox?
If yes then how it will be possible, suggest some idea? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a great article on the subject http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/autosuggestextender.aspx

A follow-up article explaining how to call an asynchronous server side auto post back event on a user's selection: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/PostbackAutoCompleteExten.aspx